# An anthology of short stories about first contact

Tags: story-identification, first-contact, anthology-book

Years ago I remember seeing an anthology of short stories about first contact, aptly titled: "First contact" (or something like that).

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very terse and would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: One of the [first four ones](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&OPERATOR_1=exact&TERM_1=first+contact&CONJUNCTION_1=AND&USE_2=title_title&OPERATOR_2=exact&TERM_2=&CONJUNCTION_2=AND&USE_3=title_title&OPERATOR_3=exact&TERM_3=&ORDERBY=title_ttype&START=0&TYPE=Title) I guess...

Comment: @Jenayah - Yuuup.

Answer (score 4):

Damon Knight edited an anthology titled *First Contact* which was published in 1971 by Pinnacle Books -- it was reprinted at least twice: [ISFDB.org](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?34655).  Might this be it?  (There were other anthologies with this title, but this is by far the most famous and IMO the best.)

Contents (from isfdb):

- 7 • Introduction (First Contact) • (1971) • essay by Damon Knight
- 9 • First Contact • (1945) • novelette by Murray Leinster
- 45 • Doomsday Deferred • (1949) • short story by Murray Leinster [as by Will F. Jenkins]
- 62 • The Hurkle Is a Happy Beast • (1949) • short story by Theodore Sturgeon
- 72 • Not Final! • [Jovians • 1] • (1941) • short story by Isaac Asimov
- 92 • The Blind Pilot • (1959) • short story by Nathalie Henneberg (trans. of Au Pilote Aveugle) [as by Charles Henneberg]
- 111 • The Silly Season • (1950) • short story by C. M. Kornbluth
- 128 • Goldfish Bowl • (1942) • novelette by Robert A. Heinlein [as by Anson MacDonald]
- 164 • In Value Deceived • (1950) • short story by H. B. Fyfe
- 177 • The Waveries • (1945) • short story by Fredric Brown
- 203 • In the Abyss • (1896) • short story by H. G. Wells

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you make the book cover any larger? I can barely see it from the moon